# Is isbndb.db working?

Tags: isbn

I'm writing a small library application/db, and I'd love to leverage isbndb.com to gather book info. Problem is, it looks like I cannot create a new account there... I always get redirected to a "Please come back later" page.
Same if I go and try to post a question on the contact page (http://isbndb.com/contact).
Sorry if the question is not pertinent... but I'm pretty stuck... I'm not finding much recent posts about isbndb.com... but it looks like the website is working well... :-)

Comment: Voting to close this question because it seems like a very temporary thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked up the registrant through whois, and contacted him.

The sign up and contact forms are now working again.

Comment: Sign up and contact forms, both not working for me. Getting this error: https://pastebin.com/yeRNHNLv. Sent an email to the registrant.